# Python regex extraer palabra con signo '+' en medio

Tags: python, regex

necesito extraer de una cadena de texto una serie de palabras que puede ser por ejemplo: TED, TED+PLUS, WCDWC y puede que alguna más de este tipo.  El problema lo tengo con la que tiene el signo + en medio, ya que sólo consigo extraer la primera parte antes del signo +.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
valor = re.findall(r' in use:\s([A-Z]{3,10}|[A-Z]\+[A-Z]{1,10})', texto, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
```

He probado varias opciones pero no consigo extraer TED+PLUS, sólo extrae TED sin el resto +PLUS.

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar `split('+')`?

Answer (score 0):

Esta expresión regular separa las palabras que contienen un "+":

```
([A-Z]+)[+]?([A-Z]*)
```

Se lee así:

- `([A-Z]+)` Pide uno o más letras y captura el calce encontrado.
- `[+]?` Reconoce cero o un caracter "+" (O sea, un "+" opcional).
- `([A-Z]*)` Reconoce y captura cero o más letras a continuación.

Lo bello es que usando `re.findall`, el *match object* resultante siempre retornara una tupla con dos entradas: el nombre y el apellido (o un string vacio, si no tiene apellido).

Este patrón no sirva para validar, pues reconoce palabras como "ABC+" que no son tiene apellido.

#### Demo

```
import re

palabras = ["TED", "TED+PLUS", "WCDWC"]

patron = re.compile("([A-Z]+)[+]?([A-Z]*)")
for palabra in palabras:
    m = patron.findall(palabra)
    nombre, apellido = m[0]
    print(nombre, apellido)
```

produce:

```
TED 
TED PLUS
WCDWC 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo estás buscando con esa expresión regular (ojo al `|`) es:
Un conjunto de 3 a 10 caracteres en mayúscula **o** un conjunto de un caracter seguido de un signo + y entre 1 y 10 caracteres al final.

Desconozco la utilidad del `[A-Z]` posterior a la `|`, pero a mi entender tienes dos opciones:

- Simplificar la expresión a algo como: `([A-Z]{3,10}\+[A-Z]{1,10})`.
- Crear un subgrupo en la primera parte de la expresión (antes del +): `(([A-Z]{3,10}|[A-Z])\+[A-Z]{1,10})`

Con expresiones regulares el uso de herramientas como https://regex101.com/ puede ayudarte mucho.

Comment: No veo una respuesta a la pregunta. ¿Dónde está la solución al problema planteado?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas, especialmente a José Antonio por la segunda propuesta que me ha ayudado a ver la solución.  Repito, muchas gracias.